# Div keeps overlapping a image

Tags: css, overlapping

My Div keeps on overlapping @ http://cyberbat.co.uk/tuts/test.php the image, is there anyway to stop it?

Comment: You'd be much better off actually posting the relevant markup and css within the question. `:)`

Comment: You could just look at the page source. I don't really want to copy and paste my code.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of `margin-left: -190px` on the text box.

Comment: I tried that and it did not work. It just made it move right.

Comment: You just asked how to keep from overlapping. That was what was causing the overlap. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? The question you asked was answered, but maybe the question wasn't clear enough.

Comment: I fixed it myself by moving the textbox into another div.

Comment: Almost fixed. Still some overlap.